# IOException On Download File Android v 2.2 eclipse kepler Android

Tags: android, download, httpurlconnection

I am using this code to download files:

```
public void Download() {
        // ========== Download Files
        String url = "[http://8pic.ir/images/7rhypy9ai9m177xaca7t.png][1]";
        String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length());
        downloadPath = G.DIR_APP + fileName;

        Log.i("Log", "fileName: " + fileName);
        Log.i("Log", "URL: '" + url + "'");
        Log.i("Log", "Local Download Path: " + downloadPath);

        FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader();
        OnDownloadListener listener = new OnDownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownload(int id, int catid, String fileName,
                                   String currentTime) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageDetail imageDetail = new ImageDetail();
                imageDetail.setDetails(id, catid, fileName, currentTime);
                HolidayDB HDB = new HolidayDB();
                HDB.insertToTable("Image_Gallery", imageDetail);
                Log.i("Log", "Imaeg Details Inserted To DataBase On Date: " +
                                imageDetail.getImage_Date() +
                                "\n" +
                                " At Time: " + imageDetail.getImage_Time() +
                                "\n" +
                                " With Name: " + imageDetail.getImage_Name() +
                                "\n" +
                                " ID: " + imageDetail.getID() +
                                "\n" +
                                " CatID: " + imageDetail.getCatID()
                );
            }
        };
        fileDownloader.download(url,
                downloadPath,
                fileName,
                prdItems.get(0).id,
                prdItems.get(0).catid,
                listener);
    }
```

and `FileDownloader` :

```
    public class FileDownloader {

                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                public void download(String urlPath, String filePath, String fileName , int fileID, int fileCatID, OnDownloadListener
 listener){
                    G.bldDownloagding = true;
                    try {
                        Log.i("Log", "urlPath is: " + urlPath);
                        urlPath = "http://8pic.ir/images/7rhypy9ai9m177xaca7t.png";
                        URL url =  new URL(urlPath);
                        HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        // connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.connect();

                        long fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
                        File file = new File(filePath);
                        if(file.exists()){
                            long localFileSize = file.length();
                            // Delete File If Exist
                            if(fileSize != localFileSize){
                                file.delete();
                            }
                        }

                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[G.DL_BUFFER_SIZE];
                        int len = 0;
                        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);

                            if(listener != null){
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
                                String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                                listener.onDownload(fileID, fileCatID, fileName, strDate);
                            }
                        }
                        outputStream.close();
                        inputStream.close();

                        Log.i("Log", "File Downloaded: " + filePath);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        ExceptionHelper.catchMessage(e);
                        Log.e("Log","Error Downloading: " + filePath + " From URL: " + urlPath);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        ExceptionHelper.catchMessage(e);
                        Log.e("Log","Error Building Connection");
                    }
                }

             }
```

Listener:

```
 public interface OnDownloadListener {
    public void onDownload(int id, int catid, String fileName, String currentTime);
 }
```

ImageDetail:

```
 public class ImageDetail {

    public int id;
    public int catid;
    public String image_name;
    public String image_date;

    public void setDetails(int id, int catid, String image_name, String image_date){
        this.id = id;
        this.catid = catid;
        this.image_name = image_name;
        this.image_date = image_date;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getCatID(){
        return catid;
    }

    public String getImage_Name(){
        return image_name;
    }

    public String getImage_Date(){
        return image_date.substring(0, image_date.indexOf(" ")).trim();
    }

    public String getImage_Time(){
        return image_date.substring(image_date.indexOf(" "), image_date.length());
    }

 }
```

image:

[image]

Comment: you nead to Log exception e, and then tell us

Comment: it shows : 08-12 22:55:15.480    1799-1813/com.example.JsonTest E/Log﹕ Error Building Connection: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Android/data/Holiday/db/01.jpg/01.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Android/data/Holiday/db/01.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)